# Allow users to delete their own comment PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, comments, sql-delete

I want to allow my users to delete their own comments from a database via a link. However the issue I'm having is that my comment doesn't delete and I'm not given any error messages.

This is the link to my "deletepost.php" page in my "salonpage.php":

```
if ($row['userID'] == $_SESSION['userID']){
$str_comments .=" <p><a href='deletepost.php?pID=".$row['ID']."&salonid=$salonid'>Delete comment</a>";
```

And this is the code in my "deletepost.php" page:

```
<?php
  require_once("checklog.php");
  require_once("nifunctions.php");

  $postID = trim($_GET['pID']);

  if ($postID != '' && is_numeric($postID))
  {
      if (!$db_server)
       {
        die("unable to connect to database: ".mysqli_connect_error($db_server));
       }
       else
       {
         $_GET['salonid'] and ($_GET['salonid'] != '');
         $salonid = clean_string($db_server, $_GET['salonid']);

         mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database) or die ("couldnt find database");

         //Delete post from comments
         $query= "DELETE FROM comments WHERE ID=$postID";
         mysqli_query($db_server,$query) or 
         die("comment delete failed" . mysqli_error($db_server));

         //redirect back to index page
         header("Location: salonpage.php?salonid=$salonid");

       }
       //db close
       mysqli_close($db_server);
   }
?>
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: If you're not getting any errors, try including the following lines of code: 
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

Comment: I think it's breaking on this line: `$_GET['salonid'] and ($_GET['salonid'] != '');`. What is that supposed to be?

Comment: I'm having a "Déjà Vue"

Comment: You can debug by doing echo $query ;  and see what you are getting.

Comment: Yeah @Fred-ii- I managed to sort out the other errors (getting the linking to work) but I thought it was too complicated to carry on in the same thread!

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash I'm not getting any errors

Comment: I hope someone solves it for you, I couldn't wrap my head around it anymore. @user3095683

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I tried that however still didn't get any errors

Comment: Check your server's error log, there must be something in there

Comment: Have you used `var_dump();` on your elements? @user3095683

Comment: @Mave this don't do anything but not break the code.

Comment: I managed to fix it! I changed my query to:

//Print out existing comment
$query = "SELECT comments.*, users.Username FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.ID WHERE salonID=$salonid"; 

from:
//Print out existing comment
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.ID WHERE salonID=$salonid";

Comment: Great news, glad to hear it! @user3095683

Comment: You're welcome. Just wondering if using `var_dump();` as I suggested helped you. Just being curious @user3095683

Comment: @Fred-ii- Afraid not, I just tried changing the query on a whim before and that worked

Comment: Those "whims" usually come out as `EUREKAS` lol @user3095683 --- I have my " what if " moments.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue through changing my query from:

```
//Print out existing comment
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.ID WHERE salonID=$salonid";
```

to:

```
//Print out existing comment
$query = "SELECT comments.*, users.Username FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.ID WHERE salonID=$salonid";
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the `$_GET['pID']` value to ensure it is set.

If not, your query will not be executed. Your first if will return false and you will just close your connection at the end.

Without that if, the query will be executed without erros, but will not find any register to delete.